# Problem with setting a Plugin as a new CType

Tags: plugins, typo3, backend

In order to have the full power of the TCA's `showitem` for configuring the back-end form for a plugin, I define it as a new CType, instead of a new `list_type` of the `list` CType.

I do this by registering it with `addPlugin` instead of the default method outlined in the official extension guide, using `registerPlugin`. In `ext_tables.php`:

```
        TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
            [
                // Label.
                'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pi1.name',
                // Plugin key.
                'myext_pi1',
                // Icon.
                'pi1'],
            'CType',
            'my_ext'
        );
```

Then I can just use, in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
 $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myext_pi1'] = [
    'showitem' => " ... "]
```

to configure it's back-end form display as I want.
But now, after successfully adding the plugin on a page from the back-end, when I try to view it from the front-end, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Content Element with uid "284" and type "myext_pi1" has no rendering definition!
```

It's not doing the usual: loading the controller action assigned to the plugin in `ext_localconf.php` with `ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin` (in `ext_localconf.php`).

Does anybody know what could I do to make it work?

Comment: Assuming that you haven't any errors in your files, the typical reason is that the extension is not included in your TS Template or it is included too late, another often problem is a requirement of **massive** cache clearing. Did you do these? Also please, update the question and add info in which file you placed these configs exactly.

Comment: @biesior Thanks again for responding. The thing is that the extension's TS is being loaded correctly since it's other plugin work as expected. Also, I've already cleared the Front-end, Back-end and all Php Cache (the option in the Install tool), so I don't think is that. I've also already updated the original post with all the file names.


What seems to be happening is that when registering the plugin with `addPlugin` instead of `registerPlugin` is like it doesn't use the controller and action, it expects a template, as if it were a custom content element. And I don't know how to change it

Comment: Adding a custom content element: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html  vs. adding a plugin: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/CreatePlugins.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point in this case is, that the element does not just "act as if it were a custom content element", but it actually IS a custom content element.

So you will have to provide at least a basic configuration via

```
tt_content.myext_pi1
```

If you registered a plugin properly it might be enough to just copy the plugin configuration to the tt_content entry

```
tt_content.myext_pi1 < plugin.myext_pi1
```

Comment: I see. I think I registered the plugin correctly, it shows up in the back-end and its database table seems to be correct. My problem is in the front-end. I registered it with `ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin` instead of `registerPlugin`, to be able to create it as a new CType instead of the `list` CType.

I've tried putting your second code snippet in my `setup.typoscript` and I still have the same error. Makes sense since it's registered as a CE not as a Plugin.

Comment: registerPlugin is just a wrapper for addPlugin, so there should not be any difference regarding the TypoScript configuration.

Comment: I've also tried with `tt_content.ndthemes_pi1 < lib.plugin` and still the same error.
I'm really wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible: on the one hand treat it as a custom CE (to be able to modify the back-end with `showitem`) and on the other as a Plugin (to load its default action, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Since it is referenced within `registerPlugin`.

Comment: If there is no key for your plugin in the TypoScript section, you might have forgotten to call \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin to have it autogenerated for extensions based on Extbase. We don't use Extbase at all here, so there usually would be something like lib.contentElement to base your configuration on. But for Extbase extensions IIRC configurePlugin is mandatory.

Comment: You could even set the pluginType to "CType" via parameter of "configurePlugin" and stick to the original registerPlugin method, to register your element as a new content element.

Comment: I literally just added `'CType'` as the fifth argument to `configurePlugin` and it worked, it reached the controller action. Just by adding this. Thank you so much man! It would have been impossible to figure this out on my own.

Comment: official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html